# Does OC4J support HTTP Strict Transport Security?

Tags: apache, security, http, oc4j

I am trying to set our OC4J servers to use HTTP Strict Transport Security, but when I add the following to the Apache confs I get a start up error:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
```

The error I get is:

/tmsv10s/app/astens/product/10.1.3/OracleAS_1/Apache/Apache/bin/apachectl startssl: execing httpd
Syntax error on line 1143 of /tmsv10s/app/astens/product/10.1.3/OracleAS_1/Apache/Apache/conf/httpd.conf:
Header takes two or three arguments, an action, header and value

I've tried in ssl.conf and httpd.conf.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oc4j is the Java container technology, nothing to do with the webserver. Oracle 10g uses Apache 1.3 (and IIRC, extended support is due to run out soon). You can verify this by running `httpd -v` from the command line or checking the start up messages in the error_log.

You need to remove the extra word "always"

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains;"
```

Answer (score 0):

With the version of Apache which comes with OC4J, you need to use the following command:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
```

I added the command in the httpd.conf just before the virtual hosts and then restarted the server.